# Segmentation fault caused by specific numbers when constructing Hash Table

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm currently trying to construct a hash table without using the Standard Template Library, however I'm having a segmentation fault problem.

Certain key values will cause a segmentation fault error in the program and I'm unsure why, those values are 21, 22 & 23. What is wrong with my code?

This program is run on C++03, the problem occurs when comparing if the function pointer to the next node is NULL.

```cpp
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
    int value;
    Node* next;
    Node(){};
    ~Node(){};
    Node(int intValue){value = intValue; next = NULL;};
};

class HashTable{
    public:
    Node* nodeArray[100];
    HashTable(){};
    void insert(int key, int value);
};

int main(){
HashTable hashTable;
    hashTable.insert(3, 4);
    hashTable.insert(99, 0);
    hashTable.insert(99, 23);
    hashTable.insert(21, 3); //This will cause the error. Other numbers 
                             //include 22 & 23.
    hashTable.insert(0, 233);
    hashTable.insert(21, 4);
}

void HashTable::insert(int key, int value){
        cout << key << endl;
    Node* newNode = new Node(value);

    if(nodeArray[key] == NULL){
        nodeArray[key] = newNode;
    }

    else{
        Node* currentNode = nodeArray[key];

        //This while loop is where the segmentation fault occurs
        while (currentNode -> next != NULL){
            currentNode = currentNode -> next;  
        }
        currentNode -> next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
3
99
99
21
0
21
```

Actual output:

```
3
99
99
21
Segmentation Fault
```

Comment: You should initialize `nodeArray` to null pointers in the constructor. If not, it can contain garbage and crash randomly. For example, when I execute it, it crashes when inserting 99.

Comment: Also, you must `delete` what you `new`. You would currently directly leak memory in every `insert` because you unconditionally create a new node that you never `delete`.

Comment: In addition, you should initialize `Node` in the default constructor.  It seems that is where most of your problems lie -- failure to initialize all of your object's member variables on construction.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé Appreciate the quick response! I did as you said and it fortunately resolved the segmentation fault, but instead created an infinite while loop! Any extra insights?

Edit: Got it!! Appreciate the help! I had to initialise the node within the default constructor as another helper suggest! 

Thanks for letting me know about the randomness that can occur if not manually initialising an array!

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MaxLanghof! If I were to delete a node that contained another node attached through the next variable, would that node be deleted too?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Your comment helped me figure out the last part of the puzzle as to why there was an infinite loop! Appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `nodeArray` and `next` in their respective constructors:

```
HashTable()
{
    for(size_t i=0; i<100; ++i)
        nodeArray[i] = NULL;
}

Node()
    : value(0)
    , next(NULL)
{
}
```

If not, they can contain garbage and crash randomly. For example, when I execute the original code, it crashes when inserting 99.

Moreover, you need to destroy nodes in the `HashTable` destructor to avoid memory leak:

```
~HashTable()
{
    for(size_t i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        Node * node = nodeArray[i];
        while(node != NULL)
        {
              Node * current_node = node;
              node = node->next;
              delete current_node;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Consider doing a move/copy constructor/assignment, or make it noncopyable to avoid memory leak and corruption.

Comment: You should also initialize the `value` field in the `Node` class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right. I edited my answer to include it. Thanks!